# Changing the time zone in all Clickhouse databases

Tags: database, clickhouse

The Linux server clock is based on Asia/Istanbul, but when a column is based on DateTime, it does not store the time based on Asia/Istanbul.
Based on the searches I had, it seems that the time zone can be specified during the creation of the table, but I plan to change the click house time zone to Asia/Istanbul in my settings.
How do I do this?

tip:
previously file `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml` I edited and added the defaults section and restarted Click House, but it got an error and didn't work.
`<timezone>Asia/Istanbul</timezone>`

**The problem was solved**

The problem was with DBeaver, DBeaver automatically changed the clock of the columns based on its settings, but when we display the columns from the CLI click house, the clock is set correctly and based on the local location.

Answer (score 0):

it's a server setting (not users.xml)

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-server-config-files/

```
cat /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/timezone.xml
<clickhouse>
  <timezone>Asia/Istanbul</timezone>
</clickhouse>
```

Also Clickhouse store data in UTC timezone internally.

Timezone settings impact only text representation during insert and select.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I executed the commands you said, then I restarted ClickHouse, but it didn't work, the time is displayed correctly in Python datetime.datetime.now() and we save the same time in ClickHouse, but it changes and becomes UTC time.

Comment: share cat /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/timezone.xml

Comment: I took a screenshot of the command  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pp0p.png

Comment: did you restart CH after ?

Comment: yes. `clickhouse restart`

Comment: no idea then, it's unclear what is the problem.

Comment: There is no alternative solution? For example, can you change the timezone when creating a database?

Comment: please show the example. How you create table. How insert data. How you query data. What is the issue.

Comment: the problem was with DBeaver, DBeaver automatically changed the clock of the columns based on its settings, but when we display the columns from the CLI click house, the clock is set correctly and based on the local location.